# How to remove order history tab?

Tags: admin, sales-order, magento-2.1.3

How to remove order history tab from magento2 admin sales order view page?

I am using the following code in `sales_order_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
    <action method="removeTab">
        <argument name="name" type="xsi:string">order_history</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

But, i am getting the exception like

> Exception: Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in
>   /vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Tabs.php on line 479

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for someone who wants to remove the comments history tab, you need to add the following to your custom sales_order_view.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="removeTab">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">order_history</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to create customer_account.xml into your module or under theme

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I wanted to remove the tab in admin sales view section.

Comment: @Sree Better do it via ACL , that is the right way if you want to hide the menu